# Error message, "hpPlugInInit.kext was installed improperly"

Tags: macos, install, printing, kernel, kernel-extensions

I recently bought a MacBook Air and transferred my system information and user data via Migration Assistant. I used to get error messages on my old computer like this:

> The system extension “/System/Library/Extensions/hpPlugInInit.kext”
>   was installed improperly and cannot be used. Please try reinstalling
>   it, or contact the product’s vendor for an update

I hoped that this would go away with the new computer. (No, that's not why I bought it but it was supposed to be a good side-effect!)

But now I'm still getting this error message when installers are running. I don't have any HP printers, but I did at one time. How can I get this error message to stop? [According to the HP support website there is an uninstaller I can run](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mac-Printing-and-Scanning/Improper-installation-of-hpPlugininit-kext/td-p/1721255), but I don't have any such uninstaller.

Comment: sounds like HP crapware was installed - with OS X there really is no need for their software as the printers can use Apple drivers. you should manually remove the kernel extension (carefully)

Comment: @JohnWoods: What's the best way to manually remove the kernel extension in a safe manner? Of course backup is the first option, but otherwise what's the procedure, and how to check to make sure it's not going to screw up my system?

Answer (score 1):

Manually deleting `hpPlugInInit.kext` under `/System/Library/Extensions/` gave me a solution.